# undefined variable when fetching query from sanity using json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, google-oauth, sanity

I am working on a react application, I've set up sanity as my backend and I am using user data via google's authentication login, user data are being successfully stored in sanity database for every google account, but as I am trying to fetch the user's data from the database to display the image of the user's profile of his google account, the image source was always failing giving me the alt tag, I console.log the variable and it is giving me an undefined type, I think it is a problem in my json.parse part in home.jsx line 14, but I don't know where I am specifically missing out, can you figure out the problem?

home.jsx:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { HiMenu } from "react-icons/hi";
import { AiFillCloseCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { userQuery } from '../utils/data';
import { Sidebar, UserProfile } from '../components';
import Pins from './Pins';
import { client } from '../client';
import logo from '../assets/speedograph.png';

const Home = () => {
  const [toggleSidebar, setToggleSidebar] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : localStorage.clear();

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = userQuery(userInfo?.googleId);

    client.fetch(query)
      .then((data) => {
        setUser(data[0]);
      })
  }, []);
  
  console.log(user?.userName);
  return (
    <div className='flex bg-gray-50 md:flex-row flex-col h-screen transaction-height duration-75 ease-out'>
      <div className='hidden md:flex h-screen flex-initial'>
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div className='flex md:hidden flex-row'>
        <HiMenu fontSize={40} className="cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setToggleSidebar(false)} />
        <Link to="/">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-28" />
        </Link>
        <Link to={`user-profile/${user?._id}`}>
        <img src={user?.picture} alt="logo" className='w-28'/>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

login.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import carVideo from '../assets/car.mp4';
import logo from '../assets/speedograph white.png';
import { client } from '../client';


const Login = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
    var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    console.log(userObject)
    if (userObject) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userObject));
      const doc = {
            _id: userObject.sub,
            _type: 'user',
            userName: userObject.name,
            image: userObject.picture,
          };
          client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
            navigate('/', { replace: true });
          });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN,
      callback: responseGoogle
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("messi"),
      {theme: "outline", size: "large"}
    );
  }, []);

  

  return (
    <div className = "flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen">
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
        <video 
          src={carVideo}
          type='video/mp4'
          loop
          controls={false}
          muted
          autoPlay
          className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />
        <div className = "absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay">
          <div className="p-5 ml-3">
            <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <div className='shadow-2xl'>
            <button id="messi" className='bg-white flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none'></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

data.js(where I think may be also the cause of the problem):

```
export const userQuery = (userId) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == '${userId}']`;

    return query;
}
```

I was expecting to get the user's google account picture on my website but all I get is the alt "logo" which indicates it failed to get the link, I tried to console.log the link of the photo and it turned out it is undefined, so there is a problem in fetching data from the database or failing to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I just passed userInfo.picture instead of user?.picture